# ASP.NET Core Web API Logging from a Static Class

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, static-classes

I'm logging just fine using dependency injection on my controllers, now I need to log something **from** a static class.

How can I log **from** a static class?

I can't use dependency injection because it's static and I can't just pass in an existing logger object to the static class because it would have the wrong name of class in the log file.

In other words how can I get a logger from the loggerfactory inside my static class?

I came across a similar question and they pointed to an article on a loggerfactory in a static class but that doesn't actually work as I can't get a new logger from it because it won't accept a static class as the parameter:

"Static types cannot be used as type arguments"

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I want to log from an extension method.

Comment: Solution here @illug

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50712720/11635

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Solution is to have a static reference to the LoggerFactory in a utility static class initialized on startup:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Shared logger
/// </summary>
internal static class ApplicationLogging
{
    internal static ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory { get; set; }// = new LoggerFactory();
    internal static ILogger CreateLogger<T>() => LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<T>();        
    internal static ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName) => LoggerFactory.CreateLogger(categoryName);
}
```

Which you initialize on Startup.cs:

```cs
public Startup(ILogger<Startup> logger, ILoggerFactory logFactory, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    _log = logger;
    _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    Util.ApplicationLogging.LoggerFactory = logFactory;//<===HERE
}
```

Then you can build a logger to use from your static class like so:

```cs
internal static class CoreJobSweeper
{
    private static ILogger log = Util.ApplicationLogging.CreateLogger("CoreJobSweeper");
}
```

Comment: Perfect! However just worth adding an example of a strongly-typed CreateLogger, especially for us copy/paste junkies just looking for a quick fix to a problem :) i.e. private static ILogger log = Util.ApplicationLogging.CreateLogger<CoreJobSweeper>();

Comment: This no longer works as if the announcement in https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/353. 

Injecting ILogger and ILoggerFactory does not work.

"The new ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider can capture logs from early in the application-startup pipeline. Although ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider is automatically enabled in Application Insights (starting with version 2.7.1), it doesn't have an instrumentation key set up until later in the pipeline. So, only logs from Controller/other classes will be captured..."

Comment: Solution is to move ILogger<Startup> logger, ILoggerFactory logFactory to Configure()

Comment: Suggestion:  change the return Type to ILogger<T> :  internal static ILogger<T> CreateLogger<T>() => LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<T>();   Usage:  private static ILogger<CoreJobSweeper> log = Util.ApplicationLogging.CreateLogger<CoreJobSweeper>();   Otherwise explicit cast is mandantory

Comment: But what if static class is in project/dll with no ref to server project with startup ?

Comment: How to implement something similar to static logger in azure function .net core 3.1 or higher @spottedmahn

Comment: Hello... how to do this in .NET Core 6 where there is no `Startup` class?

Answer (score 21):

I found this question with answers useful, but I remembered I already have installed Serilog. Instead of implementing a custom static instance, I could use the default implementation from Serilog.

It comes with multiple nice logging features with multiple overloaded version.
Here are two examples:

```
using Serilog;
...
    Log.Error(myException, "my message");
    Log.Warning("My message", myValue);
```

`Serilog.Log` is a static instance that is ready when configured in Program.cs or Startup.cs.

Comment: This works if you don´t need to use the separation of concerns principle where you could replace the logging framework easily if needed.

Comment: True, and if one would like to use Serilog in a custom logger, one can let the custom logger basically be a wrapper around Serilog :) To get a binding to the calling class, as OP asked for, one can implement something like the factorymethod with type parameter as [@Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54234887/3032543) described.

Comment: You are coding to a concrete, not coding to an interface.  Future readers, just "be aware" of this situation.

Comment: @Banshee - This works if you don't want to rely on **Abstraction** where you could replace the logging framework easily if needed.

Comment: As clarification to my last comment: **Separation of Concerns** is an observation of the different *Vertical* Concerns of an application: Design, UI Logic, API, BLL, DLL, Persistence. **Cross-Cutting Concerns** is when you share logic *Horizontally* at a particular layer.  ie: Auth (or Logging, Caching, etc) is a CCC across API1, API2, API3, etc.  Lastly, **Bounded Context** is observing ownership (Low Coupling, High Cohesion) of models between *Horizontally*-Split applications or MicroServices.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the static `LoggerFactory` instance with the following extension method which accepts a regular parameter of type `Type`, rather than a generic type parameter:
[CreateLogger(ILoggerFactory, Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerfactoryextensions.createlogger?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_LoggerFactoryExtensions_CreateLogger_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_ILoggerFactory_System_Type_)

i.e. `loggerFactory.CreateLogger(typeof(T))` rather than `loggerFactory.CreateLogger<T>()`

Comment: Did you mean "**_a_** static `LoggerFactory` instance"? There is no static `LoggerFactory` instance available unless you set one up.

Answer (score 1):

I've added a static member of ILoggerFactory in `Startup` class so it can be used in other classes.

```csharp
public class Startup
{
    internal static ILoggerFactory LogFactory { get; set; }
    …

    public void Configure(…, ILoggerFactory logFactory)
    {
        …
        LogFactory = logFactory;
    }
}
```

Then use it in the static class.

```csharp
static class YourClass
{
    private static ILogger<YourClass> Logger = Startup.LogFactory.CreateLogger<YourClass>();
…
```

However, this code will result in a TypeInitializationException when the CreateLogger throws an exception, so you should try to do better. [[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors#Remarks)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I agree with [NightOwl888](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48677330/2833802) answer.

But as an option (consider this as a workaround) you could inject `ILogger` dependency via method parameter => so a class that will call this static method should be responsible for providing a correct implementation of `ILogger`.

```
static class YourClass
{
    public static void DoSomething(ILogger logger)
    {
         // do something
         // call log.Log();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nightowl didn't answer the question at all and instead delivered an unwanted lecture, I specifically covered what you suggest and why I can't do it in my question.

Comment: To be able to log Everywhere, you have to force a required logger dependency on every method/object in your tens of thousands of lines of code. That sounds like a terrible idea to me. A static factory is the saner option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For .net core 7/.net7, I have prepared static logger class which has a initialization method to initialize an instance of static ILogger object from ILoggerFactory

```
public static class LogHelperService{

    private static ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
    private static ILogger _logger;
    private static IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public static void Initialize(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
        _logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger("LogHelperService");
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    
    public static void LogError( Exception exception, string message, params object[] args)
    {
        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, exception, message, args);
    }
    public static void LogError( string message, params object[] args)
    {
        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, message, args);
    }
    public static void LogInformation(string message, params object[] args)
    {
        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, message, args);
    }
    public static void LogInformation(Exception exception, string message, params object[] args)
    {
        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, exception, message, args);
    }
}
```

Then In Program.js, After the app object created from WebApplicationBuilder,
I have called the Initialization function to create the static Logger

```
var app = builder.Build();

//initialize Static service with server resources
LogHelperService.Initialize( app.Services.GetService<ILoggerFactory>() ,app.Services.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>());
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the combined answer of @JohnC & @Pekaaw,

LoggingFactory can be created from SeriLog logger to retain same the log configuration and it can be used for logging mechanism

(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory)Serilog.SerilogLoggerFactoryExtensions.AddSerilog(new Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory(), Serilog.Log.Logger);

```
/// <summary>
/// Shared logger
/// </summary>
internal static class ApplicationLogging
{
    internal static ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory { get; set; } = (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory)Serilog.SerilogLoggerFactoryExtensions.AddSerilog(new Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory(), Serilog.Log.Logger);
    internal static Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger CreateLogger<T>() => LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<T>();
    internal static Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName) => LoggerFactory.CreateLogger(categoryName);
}
```

```
public static class YourClass
{
   public static readonly ILogger _logger = ApplicationLogging.CreateLogger("YourClass");
   public static void MyMethod(string param)
   {
      try
      {
         _logger.LogInformation($"Inside MyMethod { param }");
         //Todo: my static code;
      }
   }
}
```