# Pattern to use Serilog (pass ILogger vs using static Serilog.Log)

Tags: c#, serilog

**Background**

In a new project where *Serilog* was chosen as the logger I automatically started passing around `ILogger` interface. The code accesses `Log.Logger` once and from then the classes that desire logging accept `ILogger` via constructor injection.

I was challenged on this practice and the advice was to use the static methods on the `Log` class, e.g. `Serilog.Log.Debug(...)`. The argument is that there is a `set;` on `Log.Logger` so mocking is easy.

Looking at the api I can see that one of the benefits of passing `ILogger` are the `ForContext` methods.

I spent some time on the webs and in the *Serilog*'s documentation but I could not find information about a canonical way to access the log throughout the application code.

**Question**

Is there a canonical, i.e. better-in-most-cases, way to access/pass around the *Serilog* logger and if there is, is it passing `ILogger` or using the static api on the `Serilog.Log` class?

Answer (score 10):

There is also a `ForContext` on `Log.Logger`, so I would not decide on that basis. If you're doing mocking/testing of logging, you don't want to do that via the single global instance. Instead, any library code that will do logging should admit an `ILogger` parameter as input, enabling the caller to instrument and/or just pass in `Log.Logger` as they see fit (don't add defaulting to `Log.Logger` internally, [for the same reasons that having a default constructor that auto-constructs dependencies that you're seeking to decouple from is a bad idea](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2013/di-anti-pattern-multiple-constructors/)). If you don't do this, you won't be able to meaningfully test logging outputs are correct (because any concurrent tests that end up running in parallel will be writing to the exact same logger instance), which is a big thing to give up.

For me, the main tradeoff is actually whether you're willing to use `Enrich.FromLogContext` and the `LogContext.*` interfaces, which hang state off the .NET `ExecutionContext`, which you need to be careful to not go crazy with. (Yes, arguably you can use a collector sequestered in the `ExecutionContext` to hack around my previous point, but don't even go there.)

Depending on how your DI is rigged, you may want to take an `ILogger<T>` in your inputs, but again, unless someone needs to be able to instrument to grab the info, having a `static ILogger _logger = Log.ForContext<MyClass>()` is fine as long as the `Log` is wired up early enough.

Comment: This is the first project where I use `Serilog` and I just don't if we end using `Enrich.FromLogContext` or other advanced features. 

Yes, the parallelization was the bit I'm most worried about. I think `ILogger` it is.

Comment: Enrich.FromLogContext is powerful and not something to shy away from - it has a very important role to play and scales plenty well. My cautionary note is only to dissuade you from trying to write tests that use/abuse `E.FLC` as a way to handle parallelism - while that can be made to work, it's unnecessarily mind-bending and entirely avoidable. Using E.FLC and the static logger is perfectly reasonable to do where testing of logging is not a concern. (also, if trapping, write your own ILogSink, don't muck about whith the observable sink etc, unless you're a real RX-fiend)

Comment: I didn't catch why and in which case tests can never run in parallel??

Comment: @RubenBartelink Now the point became pretty clean for me! Thank you!