# Static logger aspnetcore webapi serilog

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I am about to implement logging in some web apis I am writing.

The default implementation suggests that everywhere I want to use logging I need to inject.

What is wrong with a static logger(serilog)without the need of injecting everywhere.

Am I missing the point?

I did see this thread (before somebody jumps with duplicate)

[ASP.NET Core Web API Logging from a Static Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48676152/asp-net-core-web-api-logging-from-a-static-class)

In the thread above mentioned i dont see how I can integrate with serilog?

As anybody implemented a serilog static logger netcore?

thanks

Comment: This is just a matter of personal preference. I prefer to use the static logger so that I won't have to inject my loggers everywhere and pollute my constructors...