# How to create a LoggerFactory with a ConsoleLoggerProvider?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

The [ConsoleLoggerProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.console.consoleloggerprovider) has four constructors:

1. `ConsoleLoggerProvider(IConsoleLoggerSettings)`
2. `ConsoleLoggerProvider(IOptionsMonitor<ConsoleLoggerOptions>)`
3. `ConsoleLoggerProvider(Func<String,LogLevel,Boolean>, Boolean)`
4. `ConsoleLoggerProvider(Func<String,LogLevel,Boolean>, Boolean, Boolean)`

Three of them are declared obsolete with this message:

> This method is obsolete and will be removed in a future version. The recommended alternative is using LoggerFactory to configure filtering and ConsoleLoggerOptions to configure logging options.

With constructor #3, creating a `LoggerFactory` with a `ConsoleLoggerProvider` is straightforward (as documented on [Entity Framework Core - Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging)):

```cs
var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(new[] { new ConsoleLoggerProvider((category, level) => level >= LogLevel.Information, true) });
```

But since it's deprecated, we are left with constructor #2. Here's what I found to be equivalent:

```cs
var configureNamedOptions = new ConfigureNamedOptions<ConsoleLoggerOptions>("", null);
var optionsFactory = new OptionsFactory<ConsoleLoggerOptions>(new []{ configureNamedOptions }, Enumerable.Empty<IPostConfigureOptions<ConsoleLoggerOptions>>());
var optionsMonitor = new OptionsMonitor<ConsoleLoggerOptions>(optionsFactory, Enumerable.Empty<IOptionsChangeTokenSource<ConsoleLoggerOptions>>(), new OptionsCache<ConsoleLoggerOptions>());
var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(new[] { new ConsoleLoggerProvider(optionsMonitor) }, new LoggerFilterOptions { MinLevel = LogLevel.Information });
```

This seems overly complicated, am I missing something simpler?

Comment: With .NET5 it's gotten worse, not better.....

Answer (score 151, accepted):

In [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/) 3.0+, you can use the much simpler [LoggerFactory.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerfactory.create):

```csharp
var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
{
    builder.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning)
           .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning)
           .AddFilter("SampleApp.Program", LogLevel.Debug)
           .AddConsole();
});
```

For Microsoft.Extensions.Logging version 2.2+, you can build an `ILoggerFactory` without using obsolete methods via Microsoft's dependency injection framework. It's a little less verbose than the 2.1 version where everything is constructed *by hand*. Here’s how:

```csharp
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder => builder
    .AddConsole()
    .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)
);
var loggerFactory = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider()
    .GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
```

See also:

- [Migrate from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.1 to 2.2 or 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/migration/logging-nonaspnetcore)

Pay attention to adding the nuget package:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console
```

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803925/136285

Comment: That's great for application composition, but what about when I'm writing test or working with REPL? It would be nice to be able to fulfill `ILogger` dependencies in a more straightforward manner. `LoggerFactory` is almost short enough, but the discoverability is not ideal...

Comment: FYI first example .AddConsole() requires a reference to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console

Comment: something goes completely wrong @microsoft, when for such a simple task we need a dependency injection and a whole bunch of options, providers and factories

Comment: python_kaa obviously doesn't understand DI

Comment: More likely, MSFT needs to revisit framework design best practices.

Comment: I find it ironic for MSFT to preach here about DI, when the whole point of DI is to decouple dependencies -- instead everywhere we seem to find god-tier dependencies on Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Comment: Mark Seemann wrote this in his [Conforming Container](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/conforming-container/) blog post: Additionally, it looks like the new Dependency Injection support for ASP.NET is taking this route as well, although hopefully, it's not too late to change that. Today is roughly 10 years later and, well, it is too late! 

Answer (score 11):

Just in case, if someone wants to do it in ASP.NET Core composition root for efcore:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(opt => {
    opt.AddSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    opt.UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.Create(builder => { builder.AddConsole(); }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@0xced thanks for your deconstructed example, since delegates don't work in Powershell this helped me to do the same in Powershell:

```
$optionsFactory = [OptionsFactory[ConsoleLoggerOptions]]::new(
    [List[ConfigureNamedOptions[ConsoleLoggerOptions]]]@(
        [ConfigureNamedOptions[ConsoleLoggerOptions]]::new('',$null)
    ),
    [List[IPostConfigureOptions[ConsoleLoggerOptions]]]::new()
)

$optionsMonitor = [OptionsMonitor[ConsoleLoggerOptions]]::new(
    $optionsFactory,
    [List[IOptionsChangeTokenSource[ConsoleLoggerOptions]]]::new(),
    [OptionsCache[ConsoleLoggerOptions]]::new()
)

$consoleLoggerProvider = [ConsoleLoggerProvider]$OptionsMonitor
$consoleLoggerProviderList = [List[ILoggerProvider]]::new()
$consoleLoggerProviderList.add($consoleLoggerProvider)

$loggerFactory = [LoggerFactory]::new(
    $consoleLoggerProviderList,
    [LoggerFilterOptions]@{
        MinLevel = [LogLevel]::Information
    }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

@Justin-Grote's answer worked for me. Here is C# version of the code.

```
            var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
        var optionsFactory = new OptionsFactory<ConsoleLoggerOptions>(
            new List<ConfigureNamedOptions<ConsoleLoggerOptions>>()
            {
                new ConfigureNamedOptions<ConsoleLoggerOptions>("", null)
            },
            new List<IPostConfigureOptions<ConsoleLoggerOptions>>()
        );

        var optionsMonitor = new OptionsMonitor<ConsoleLoggerOptions>(
            optionsFactory,
            new List<IOptionsChangeTokenSource<ConsoleLoggerOptions>>(),
            new OptionsCache<ConsoleLoggerOptions>()
        );
        var consoleLoggerProvider = new ConsoleLoggerProvider(optionsMonitor);
```