# .NET Core 3.0 ConsoleLoggerFactory for SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2, .net-core-3.0

using latest .Net Core (3.0 preview) and EF Core (3.0 preview) looking at a few online sources I did this:

**Program.cs**

```
public class MainWorker : IHostedService {

  public static readonly ILoggerFactory ConsoleLoggerFactory =
     LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole();
```

**MyDbContext.cs**

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
  string connectionString = ...
    optionsBuilder
      .UseLoggerFactory(MainWorker.ConsoleLoggerFactory)
      .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true)
      .UseSqlite(connectionString);
    }
```

This all builds and runs fine but when using EF to query my DB instead of the actual SQL queries I *only* see are entries such as:

> info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
>         Entity Framework Core 3.0.0-preview4.19176.6 initialized 'MyDbContext' using provider
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite' with options:
>   SensitiveDataLoggingEnabled

How can I get the actual SQL query for an IQueryable ?

Any help ?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but looks like you'd only expect to get logs for warnings and above. Are you sure your code will be generating any EF warnings/errors?

Comment: I'm not, got it from - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690820/how-to-create-a-loggerfactory-with-a-consoleloggerprovider - I'm not sure what `AddFilter` does, can't find docs

Comment: ok I updated my question after removing AddFilter .. can you please have a look ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Based on the provided feedback, the below change has been [reverted in 3.0 preview 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#query-execution-is-logged-at-debug-level-reverted).

---

This is one of the expected [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes) in EF Core 3.0 - [Query execution is logged at Debug level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#query-execution-is-logged-at-debug-level).

The link explains why is that and how to get back the previous behavior of logging SQL at `Info` level (the default) using the `DbContextOptionsBuilder`:

```
.ConfigureWarnings(c => c.Log((RelationalEventId.CommandExecuting, LogLevel.Info)));
```

Another way is to change the minimum log level for `DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command` category to `Debug` using the `AddFilter` method of the `ILoggingBuilder`:

```
.AddFilter(DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name, LogLevel.Debug)
```

Comment: One should note that this breaking change will get reverted again: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14523

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf Well, it might or might not - one of the reasons I don't like preview (beta) versions. We'll see, for now we should rely on "official" information from EF Core documentation.