# Console Logging in .NET Core 6?

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-6.0

Using **.NET 6 Core** for a console app and I can't get debug logging working (nothing is displayed). And, I have added `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` to the project.

You'll see two ways below that I've attempted to get a reference to the logger.

Notice that `logger.LogInformation` does work, but `logger.LogDebug` does not.

**Question:** How do I get `LogDebug` working?

### Program.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                            .AddLogging(builder => {
                                builder.ClearProviders();
                                builder.AddConsole();
                                builder.AddDebug();
                            })
                            .BuildServiceProvider();

// I've tried this
var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();

// And this
var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger<Program>>();

logger.LogDebug("hello world");       // <-- This DOESN'T work
logger.LogInformation("something");   // <-- This DOES work
```

Comment: [Official docs has an excellent example of this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line#create-logs-in-main)

Comment: @AshK, unfortunately, they _didn't_ when I wrote the question almost 2 years ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the following to log `Debug`:

```
builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
```

Comment: I had done that earlier, but it didn't work. It does now for some reason??? Oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Just to have here complete working example for **.NET Core 6**.
You should add packages `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` to the project.
(In my case its version is `6.0.0`)

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console;

ServiceProvider serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddLogging((loggingBuilder) => loggingBuilder
        .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace)
        .AddConsole()
        )
    .BuildServiceProvider();

var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger<Program>();

//Now both are working
logger.LogDebug("Debug World");         
logger.LogInformation("Hello World");
```

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53693858/136285

Comment: This is what i needed. I needed to install the `Console` provider. Thanks!

Comment: Jeeze, all of the configure logging stuff was moved into AddLogging.  These intra-version changes are killing me.

Answer (score 6):

There is documentation on how to [Create logs in Main](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line#create-logs-in-main):

```cs
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).Build();
var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
logger.LogDebug("Host created.");
// ...
```

Once you have an `IHost` created via `CreateDefaultBuilder`, this allows you to take advantage of the `appsettings.json` file (see [Configure logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line#configure-logging)):

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug", // set default logs to debug level
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Just don't forget to copy `appsettings.json` to the output in your `.csproj` file. This is not done by default for Console applications and was what I was missing.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="appsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default you only get Information and above levels (Warning, Error, Critical).

You have to add configuration to get lower levels like Debug.