# Azure function logging not logging in azure application insights with LoggerFactory implementations

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I am trying to implement logger without serilog and facing an issue with static class logging with Microsoft Ilogger. I had a similar issue for .net core but I was able to solve it with [ASP.NET Core Web API Logging from a Static Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48676152/asp-net-core-web-api-logging-from-a-static-class)
solution I tried to implement similar in azure function but the message is logging in local console but not in azure application insights

**The goal is to log in Static class with Ilogger and LoggerFactory**

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MicrosoftLoggin.Startup))]
namespace MicrosoftLoggin
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddLogging(lb =>
            {
                lb.AddFilter("MicrosoftLoggin", LogLevel.Information);               
            });

            builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomer, Customer>();
            FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();

            ApplicationLogging.LoggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
            {
                builder          
                .AddFilter("MicrosoftLoggin", LogLevel.Information)
                .AddApplicationInsights()
                .AddConsole()
                .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information)
                .AddConfiguration(context.Configuration);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and trying to log like this

```
public interface ICustomer
    {
        public void TestLogging();
    }

    public class Customer : ICustomer
    {

        private readonly ILogger _logger = ApplicationLogging.CreateLogger(nameof(Customer));

        public Customer(ILogger<Customer> logger)
        {
            Logger = logger;
        }

        private ILogger<Customer> Logger { get; }

        public void TestLogging()
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("With factory logger");
            Logger.LogInformation("With Microsoft Logger");
        }
    }
```

attached the console log screnshort [image] for reference

I am able to see the "With Microsoft Logger" not the "With factory logger" message.

[image]

Comment: You need to edit the `host.json` code to log the information also!

Answer (score 0):

On your `Startup.cs`, remove these:

```
ApplicationLogging.LoggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
            {
                builder          
                .AddFilter("MicrosoftLoggin", LogLevel.Information)
                .AddApplicationInsights()
                .AddConsole()
                .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information)
                .AddConfiguration(context.Configuration);
            });
```

Also just add `builder.Services.AddLogging();` without config for its LogLevel is already set to Information by default.

Update your `Customer` class into the following:

```
public class Customer : ICustomer
    {

        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Customer(ILogger<Customer> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void TestLogging()
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("With factory logger");
        }
    }
```

You don't need the `LoggerFactory`, the `ILogger` is injected by the DI container for you. If you're running your function app locally and you want to pass your logging to Application insights, make sure you have the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` and `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING` values placed in your config file, probably inside your `appsettings.json`. You can find these values on the Configuration section of your Azure function that's running on Azure.

Comment: Logging with DI is working as expected I don't have any issue with that but logging created with LoggerFactory is not logging in APPLICATIONINSIGHTS and the reason why I am trying to use LoggerFactory is to log in static classes also @raffy

Comment: @RakeshT.R have you tried my suggested approach on your static classes? Did it work?

Comment: How can we use ILogger in static class it can be used in class with Constructor Dependency Injection only right @raffy

Comment: @RakeshT.R you can try migrating your function from in-process to isolated. The isolated function supports dependency injection for ILogger<T>